# Synchronous closing websocket in browser

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a web app using `WebSocket` to connect the server and performing an action. After the action finished, the connection is going to be closed automatically.
But the user can restart the action by pressing a button, which close connection then create a new connection.

Example code when user restart the action:

```
if (this.connection) {
    this.connection.close()
    // this.connection = null
}

if (!this.connection) {
    this.connection = new WebSocket(serverSocketURL)

    // Other logic codes here

    this.connection.onclose = () => {
        this.connection = null
    }
}
```

The problem is `close()` method is async so the second block code run before the connection is closed.
How to synchronous closing `WebSocket` connection?
Should I use `setTimeout` to wait a small time after call `close()` method?

Comment: `this.connection` won't be falsey even once the connection closes - just don't test `!this.connection` ... just run that code - you're assigning a new connection anyway, so there's no problem doing that

Comment: I try to set `this.connection` to `null` when is closed (call after method `close()` or on event `onclose`) but is not working. User must press the button twice to close the connection and create the new one.

Comment: `this.connection.onclose = () => {
        this.connection = null
    }` is probably what's causing that - because that will only run for the old websocket **after** you've created the new one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will do what you want

When the connection is "re-connected" by the user, a second `close` listener is added to make a new connection - as this listener is added after the one that sets `this.connection = null`, it will be called after that is run, so there's no chance of a race condition

```
const makeConnection = () => {
    this.connection = new WebSocket(serverSocketURL);
    // Other logic codes here
    this.connection.addEventListener('close', () => {
        this.connection = null
    });
};
if (this.connection) {
    this.connection.addEventListener('close', makeConnection);
    this.connection.close();
} else {
    makeConnection();
}
```

or - using `onclose` instead of `addEventListener('close',`

```
const makeConnection = () => {
    this.connection = new WebSocket(serverSocketURL);
    // Other logic codes here
    this.connection.onclose = () => {
        this.connection = null
    };
};
if (this.connection) {
    this.connection.onclose = makeConnection;
    this.connection.close();
} else {
    makeConnection();
}
```

Comment: `as this listener is added after the one that sets this.connection = null, it will be called after that is run` how do you guarantee the order ?!, this behavior is not guaranteed across browsers as far as I know, and I could not find anything about  it

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher - *For event listeners attached to the event target, the event is in the target phase, rather than the capturing and bubbling phases. Events in the target phase will trigger all listeners on an element **in the order they were registered*** - straight from the documentation - is that good enough? Did you want to get it from the spec instead?

Comment: there's ways around it - could just use the `onclose` property as in the original code ... overwriting it would mean the `this.connection = null` is never run in the case of `re-opening` the websocket - I just avoid `on*` properties - old habit - in some ways, that's "easier" - so added it to the answer